# how can i embed and code cgi scripts in c++ on my mac?

Tags: c++, macos, cgi

I have searched on Google a lot and have not found any useful and comprehensive answer to the above question.
Any help is appreciated
Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "embed and code cgi scripts"? Embed where? What shoud the CGI "script" do?

Comment: I mean how can I execute them via a simple html page..Like you embed php in your html file..I read somewhere that execution of cgi scripts via a local host is done by storing them on your system(in this case, my mac) but I am curious as to whether I can use them in my html pages. If yes, how?